# When did Tom Paris and B'elanna Torres get married?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In the *Star Trek: Voyager* episode "Nightingale" this exchange occurs:

> TORRES: Don't worry about it. Bumping elbows comes with the job. And
>   you can call me B'Elanna. Put this with the others. These relays
>   should have been replaced a while ago. It's amazing they've held up
>   this long. I'm really looking forward to our climb.
>
> ICHEB: Wouldn't you prefer to spend your free time **with your
>   husband?**
>
> TORRES: If it doesn't involve a race car, a shuttle, or something else
>   he can drive, Tom's not interested. Besides, since we got married I
>   see more than enough of him. Hold still.

I know six episodes before this one, in "Drive", Paris proposes to Torres under duress (initially). She never says yes to my knowledge:

> TORRES: Why? You going to withdraw the question?
>
> PARIS: No, but I might start to beg. It could get embarrassing.
>
> Captain's log, supplemental. The Antarians have invited us to
>   participate in the post-race festivities, which has allowed me to give
>   two of my senior officers time off for a well-deserved romantic
>   getaway. The Delta Flyer still needs a new warp core, but I don't
>   think they're in a hurry to get anywhere.
>
> [Delta Flyer]
>
> (Two glasses of champagne are poured out.)
>
> PARIS: To the winners. B'Elanna Paris. That has a nice ring to it.
>
> TORRES: Thanks, but I already have a ring. Anyway, I kind of like the
>   sound of Tom Torres.
>
> PARIS: I hope you're kidding.
>
> TORRES: Hey, it is the twenty fourth century.
>
> (They kiss. The Delta Flyer glides away, with 'Just Married' painted
>   on the stern and trailing strings of cargo canisters.)

So even though Torres doesn't say on-screen, "yes" is implied.

Ok, so when did they get married? Did I miss something? Was there an episode or part of an episode I missed, or was there just this scene and then six episodes later they're married with no on-screen ceremony, etc.?

If there's any writers notes or comments by the actors about this or the lack of a wedding it is most welcome.

Comment: Of course, we — and this is a little spoilerish, so SPOILERS — “saw” them get married back in *Course: Oblivion*, but we weren’t quite seeing what we thought we were seeing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## In 2377

Specifically stardate 54058.6

The [Memory Alpha page on Paris](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tom_Paris#Romance) explains the following

> Complications in their relationship lead B'Elanna to consider ending
> it because she wondered if they really belonged together and realized
> that merely having a good time occasionally was not enough for her.
> Tom, however, reaffirmed his love and desire of wanting to be with her
> and **in 2377 they were married. (VOY: "Drive")**

The [transcript at the end of Drive](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/702.htm) confirms this:

> [Delta Flyer]
>
> (Two glasses of champagne are poured out.)
>
> PARIS: To the winners.
> B'Elanna Paris. That has a nice ring to it.
>
> TORRES: Thanks, but I already have a ring. Anyway, I kind of like the sound of Tom Torres.
> PARIS: I hope you're kidding.
>
> TORRES: Hey, it is the twenty fourth century.
>
> (They kiss. **The Delta Flyer glides away, with 'Just Married'
> painted on the stern and trailing strings of cargo canisters.)**

I have included the above image below.

To me, the script indicates that the pair *were* married at the end of the episode of *Drive*, but some of the finer details (i.e. whether they were going to adopt the surname 'Torres' or 'Paris') was yet to be finalised.

[image]

Just to give some background, they first began their romantic relationship after the events of *VOY: Day of Honor* when they were adrift in space with limited oxygen supplies.

Comment: But they weren't married in the episode Drive, right? It had to be sometime between the episode Drive and the episode "nightingale", right? Which episode did it happen in? Wasn't that picture from the demon-crew wedding, not from the actual tom and b'elanna if it was, what episode is that photo from?

Comment: @JMFB they were married at the end of *Drive*.  As for that image, [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/File:Paris-Torres_honeymoon.jpg) describes it as "The Delta Flyer II shortly after Tom Paris' and B'Elanna Torres' wedding in 2377. **(VOY: "Drive")**"

Comment: That is incorrect. I included in my quote the last words spoken in "Drive." B'elanna does not say yes directly. The captain let's them stay out in the middle of nowhere since they had to eject the warp core. They just sit out in space, toast champagne, and argue about who is taking whose last name. So it's implied that they intend on getting married but there's nothing in the episode that states that they got married, they haven't even made it back to Voyager  after the race was over as they're floating in space. Re-read the quote I put in my question.

Comment: The transcript does say that that photo is at the end of the episode. After I'm done with this one I'll rewatch the end. Sorry. Why no wedding? And they literally got married that same day and then took off? It says that it happened at the same time as the post game ceremonies, just rewatched, I missed it the first time.

Comment: Congrats, that was the easiest correct answer you ever got!

Answer (score 8):

They got married at the end of Drive (hence the "Just Married" sign, calling each other the spouses last name, and the wedding rings.) I remember an interview back when Voyager was still on the air that addressed this issue. TPTB basically stated that they did not show the wedding on air because they had already shown a P/T wedding in Course Obviation and felt like it would be redundant. Hope this clarifies things...

Answer (score 4):

They got married at the end of the episode Drive. The reason they did not have a wedding scene was because a wedding shot had already happened on the show in a previous episode called Course: Oblivion, they didn't refilm a wedding scene to save on production costs. In the very next episode after Drive called Repression the very first words ushered by Be'lanna was "Fresh Flowers? An afternoon on the holodeck? It almost feels like we're dating again." Tom responds with "The secret to a lasting marriage --- keep the romance alive"

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think this is the most accurate. Perhaps you can flesh the answer out with specifics - the season / episode as opposed to just the title f the episode? I always considered them married and did not understand why this Drive episode appeared to marry them again. But your description makes sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

So, I know this is an old thread, but looking for the answer to the when they were married question landed me here (I got curious after rewatching Course: Oblivion).

Being a Trekkie, junkie-nerd I can't resist adding my 2 cents even if it is just to confirm that they do get married in Drive and that the picture is legit and from that episode. (I knew it wasn't from Course: Oblivion as I just watched it and there are no Delta Flyer flights in that episode.)

Even though they lost the race, Tom toasts the "winners". This is in reference to B'Elanna saying they didn't win at the end of the race and Tom telling her that depends on how she answers his proposal of marriage.  When B'Elanna says, " I already have a ring", she even holds up her hand and displays the wedding  ring. We know this is not an engagement ring because in Drive the duplicates who share the same memories and cultural norms as 24th century humans use the same single band as a wedding ring with no accompanying engagement ring of any sort. Then, of course there is the big "Just Married" in the next shot.

We know they are not still drifting in space from the race because their uniforms have changed and they are drinking champagne. (Of course these could be replicated, assuming the Flyer has full replicator abilities.). The overall scene is set up to lead us to believe some time has passed (though not much as the Voyager crew are sticking around for post race festivities and the Flyer is still without a warp core) and that Janeway has not simply beamed aboard and married them or done so by com link.  This is proven by the cargo containers tethered behind the ship in lieu of cans. Replicating those and beaming them out, somehow managing to attach them in the process seems a lot more complicated than doing it in Voyager's cargo bay.

The only thing that is debatable, really is if they were still adrift and somehow replicated champagne, uniforms, a ring, cargo containers, and then attached them in space while somehow getting married aboard the Flyer. Unlikely as it is, that irrelevant detail can be debated.

We do know with 100% certainty that Paris and Torres are not married at the beginning of Drive and that by the end of the episode they are.

Tom and B'Elanna are married in Season 7 Episode 3 - without a doubt!

(No warp drive does not mean they have no impulse capability at all or that Voyager would not have come to them. In fact, it would have been the first order of business for Voyager to retrieve them.)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that they get married in Drive, but they didn't bother showing the ceremony as it had been done before with the "copy crew". I did notice that Tom Paris is already wearing his wedding ring in the previous episode when he is assisting the Doctor with Sevens operation though.[image]

Comment: The screenshot might be better if you can remove the overlay but it does add to the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have a laptop, the screen shot is the best I can do on my Samsung S7, at least with my limited technical skills.

Comment: Imperfection was originally supposed to come after Drive. Note that they had the new Flyer, too, and the stardate is way off. Refer to Memory Alpha

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so good at transferring pictures and such but I happened to notice that in the previous episode "Imperfection" at approximately "23:37 " you can clearly see Toms left hand as he hands the doctor the node for seven. It is definitely sporting a gold wedding band. You can see it elsewhere if you know what you're looking for. But this view is oThat is what led me to this question to begin with. I thought I had missed something.

Comment: So are you saying that this is when they were married?

Comment: The new Flyer's in that episode as well. The two were switched and it caused some continuity problems. Read more about it on Memory Alpha.

Answer (score 1):

"Imperfection" episode aired out of order. Since Tom Paris is clearly shown wearing a wedding band throughout the episode, it did add to the confusion of when they were married. From TV Tropes:

> If one notices in the episode, Tom Paris already has his wedding ring on. From the production notes, this episode was originally supposed to follow "Drive" where the new Delta Flyer II is being tested out and Paris marries B'elanna Torres, but somehow Executive Meddling decided to have this episode air first before "Drive"

Comment: Do you have a link for the TVTropes page you can edit in?